# Randomness of hash of string should be disabled via PYTHONHASHSEED

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

I use spark on yarn mode,I have a problem when run
    *`pyspark --master yarn`*
under python3.5 , when I run code like this
    `user_data = sc.textFile("/testdata/u.user") 
    user_fields = user_data.map(lambda line: line.split("|"))
    num_genders = user_fields.map(lambda fields: fields[2]).distinct().count()`
the result show

```
File "/data/opt/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1753, in add_shuffle_key
File "/data/opt/hadoop-2.6.0/tmp/nm-local-dir/usercache/jsdxadm/appcache/application_1494985561557_0005/container_1494985561557_0005_01_000002/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 74, in portable_hash
raise Exception("Randomness of hash of string should be disabled via PYTHONHASHSEED environ=")
```

I try but can not resolve, can you help me

Comment: I try two methods but not resolve  first: echo "export PYTHONHASHSEED=0" >> /root/.bashrc ;second:spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYTHONHASHSEED="XXXX"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include `spark.executorEnv.PYTHONHASHSEED   0` in your `spark-defaults.conf` (in your Spark ./conf directory). That should work!

Comment: I follow you advice , resolve this problem,think you

Comment: Made deal for me! Thanks!

Comment: this didn't work for me. There was also no spark-defaults.conf file in my /.conf dir, only a template. I created the file and put the above line in there, but I'm still getting the error

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem in Spark 2.1 that is resolved in 2.2.  If you are not able to upgrade or do not have access to spark-defaults.conf, you can use

```
export SPARK_YARN_USER_ENV=PYTHONHASHSEED=0
```

before you submit your job.